# the scope of this in jquery's callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery's event is as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.show-it', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       showIt();
});

function showIt() {...};
```

In the `showIt` function, when I wanna try to access `$(this)`, it always return the `window` object. As far as I know, because the `showIt` function now serves as part of a callback function, the scope of `this` in the `showIt` function should be the same as in the `.show-it` button's click callback function, which is the element clicked. But it seems to be not. I have to use `self.showIt.call(this)()` in the callback function to get the right scope of `this`. So what is going on behind the scene?

Comment: `self.showIt` doesn't make any sense. `showIt` is not a method of `self` in the code you have provided.

Comment: @KevinB: given the code shown, showIt is indeed a property of self, aka a global. the first line is redundant because self==this==window by default. that also means there's no point in saying 
"self." something, since that lexical scope name is already active via closure.

Comment: @dandavis right, but that obviously depends on what the scope is. i guess you can argue that since he didn't provide one it's safe to assume he's on the global scope, though it wouldn't make sense to use `var self = this` on the global scope.

Comment: Also, if he was in the global scope, he wouldn't get undefined for `this`. http://jsfiddle.net/Q2E9L/2/

Comment: Sorry, guys. My original code is a bit more complicated and this is a simplified version of it. I may not think through this version carefully. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery uses `callback.call(el)` or an equivalent expression to set the value of `this` to a given DOM element in a callback function. But this does not cascade down to other functions called within that callback. Try it out:

```
var o = {
    name: "baz",
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

function bar() {
    console.log(this); // bar's this
    foo();             // the global object
    foo.call(this);    // bar's this
    o.foo();           // o
    o.foo.call(this);  // bar's this
}

bar.call(new Date());
```

Output:

```
Thu Feb 13 2014 13:26:47 GMT-0800 (PST)
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location...}
Thu Feb 13 2014 13:26:47 GMT-0800 (PST) VM350:10
Object {name: "baz", foo: function}
Thu Feb 13 2014 13:26:47 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

Note that when you call a function that's a property of an object, `this` gets bound to that object, no matter what `this` is in the calling context, unless the function has been bound previously using `Function.bind`.